# Custom String Sort: How do I place these strings in an array in this particular order

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting, nsstring

/*
Hello, I'm new to swift and have stumped myself on a custom array sort.
How do I place these strings in an array in this particular order?

Camera: Prime: Filter: Support:

I can use .containsString if I use NSString
I want a dynamic array because I don't know how big the list will get eventually

Thank you for taking a look at my question!
*/

```
var equipmentList:[String]  = []

var item1   =   NSString(string: "Support: Fluid Head ")

var item2   =   NSString(string: "Prime: Ziess Master Primes")

var item3   =   NSString(string: "Filter: ND Set")

var item4   =   NSString(string: "Camera: Arri Alexa")



if item1.containsString("Camera:") {

    // place in first position in a dynamic array

}

if item1.containsString("Prime:") {

    // place in second position in a dynamic array

}

if item1.containsString("Filter:") {

    // place in third position in a dynamic array

}

if item1.containsString("Support:") {

    // place in forth position in a dynamic array

}
```

Comment: Arrays are usually used as compacted lists.  In other words, they don't have positions per se, except positions as defined by the elements currently contained.  You could use a placeholder object (maybe NSNull or an empty string) to fill a 4 element array, then replace the placeholders, or you could pick a different data structure (like a dictionary -- unordered, but keyed by something order able, like NSNumber)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Explanation are in the comments:

```
// The order by which you will sort your equipment types
let order = ["Camera", "Prime", "Filter", "Support"]


// The sorting function
func compareEquipment(equipment1: String, equipment2: String) -> Bool {
    let components1 = equipment1.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let components2 = equipment2.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

    // Each equipment string must have exactly 2 components separeted by
    // a colon (:), like in this format:
    //      equipment type: eqipment name
    //
    // If not, quit the function reporting an error
    guard components1.count == 2 && components2.count == 2 else {
        fatalError("Invalid equipment: '\(equipment1)' or '\(equipment2)'")
    }

    // The order of the equipment type
    let order1 = order.indexOf(components1.first!) ?? Int.max
    let order2 = order.indexOf(components2.first!) ?? Int.max

    // When comparing 2 equipment strings, order them by equipment type
    // first. If they are of the same type, order them by name
    if order1 != order2 {
        return order1 < order2
    } else {
        return components1.last! < components2.last
    }
}


let equipmentList = [
    "Support: Fluid Head",
    "Prime: Ziess Master Primes",
    "Filter: ND Set",
    "Camera: Arri Alexa"
]

let sortedEquipmentList = equipmentList.sort(compareEquipment)

print(sortedEquipmentList)
```

Comment: This solution.. as well as the one below worked elegantly, Thank You for the help. I see where I was going wrong now!!!!

Answer (score 0):

-- Edit --

Actually looking back at your answer, not knowing what you actually want but a more safe solution is to use an enumerator (for autocomplete and use names instead of numbers), an equipment class and an equipment list:

```
enum EquipmentType : Int {
    case Camera  = 1
    case Prime = 2
    case Filter = 3
    case Support = 4
}

class Equipment {
    let equipmentType : EquipmentType
    let name : String

    init(type : EquipmentType, name : String) {
        self.equipmentType = type
        self.name = name
    }
}

class EquipmentList {
    var equipment : [Equipment] = []

    func sortEquipment() {
        self.equipment = self.equipment.sort({$0.equipmentType.rawValue < $1.equipmentType.rawValue})
    }

    func addEquipment(equipment : Equipment) {
        self.equipment.append(equipment)
        self.sortEquipment()
    }

    func addEquipmentList(equipmentList : [Equipment]) {
        self.equipment.appendContentsOf(equipmentList)
        self.sortEquipment()
    }

    func printEquipment() {
        self.equipment.forEach() { equipment in
            print("Type: \(equipment.equipmentType) - Name: \(equipment.name)")
        }
    }
}

let equipmentList = EquipmentList()

// Adding temp equipment
let item1 = Equipment(type: .Support, name: "Fluid Head")
let item2 = Equipment(type: .Prime, name: "Ziess Master Primes")
let item3 = Equipment(type: .Filter, name: "ND Set")
let item4 = Equipment(type: .Camera, name: "Arri Alexa")

equipmentList.addEquipmentList([item1, item2, item3, item4])
equipmentList.printEquipment()
```

I think this will suit all your needs.

-- Original answer --

Maybe I do not understand the question well enough but to insert values at a specific index in an array you can use the following method:

```
Array.insert(Element, atIndex : Int)
```

To insert on the 0,1,2,3-th position you'd simply call:

```
equipmentList.insert(item1, atIndex: 0)
equipmentList.insert(item2, atIndex: 1)
equipmentList.insert(item3, atIndex: 2)
equipmentList.insert(item4, atIndex: 3)
```

If the Array is empty when you want to add the values you can also append them to the array using the append method:

```
Array.append(Element)
```

To append to the 0,1,2,3-th position given that the array is empty you'd call:

```
equipmentList.append(item1)
equipmentList.append(item2)
equipmentList.append(item3)
equipmentList.append(item4)
```

Comment: This solution.. as well as the one above worked well, Thank You for the help. I like the implementation of a class and enum. I thought about that but wasn't able to write it correctly. I see how your solution does that. Thank you very much!